# Convert factor data which was split from another column into characters

Tags: r, data-cleaning

The original data is in excel format.

I was working on the `area` column that was split from another column into `area` and `building`. The problem is I couldn't convert `area` from `factor` into `character` to proceed with following manipulations. I used `as.character(df$area)` and nothing changed.

If I try to export the data into a csv file and reload using `df <- read.csv("df.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`, it would do the job but the time column in the data set would be distorted, something like `0001-01-16, 0001-01-16, 0001-02-16`.

```
df <- structure(list(area = c("A", "B", "B", "C", 
"D", "C"), building = c("building1", "building1", "building3", "building2", "building3", "building1"), time = c("2016-08-10 09:30:01", 
"2016-08-11 09:30:01", "2016-08-12 09:30:01", "2016-08-13 09:30:01", "2016-08-14 09:30:01", "2016-08-15 09:30:01"
), count = c(2L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 2L, 5L), name = c("SA", 
"RC", "BN", "LJ", "MS", "NG"), id = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Has anyone had similar experience? Any contribution is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a date column that was split in two : year and month-day ? If the data you exported from excel to csv contained a date class column it seems to automatically try to add the year to it. The best in to set all the factor/date columns as character beforhand. However, it would be good to have a sample of your r data to provide further insight

Comment: Hi Tom, the column that was split from another one is not a date, but categorical data. The time data is a totally different column which is originally in the format `2016-08-10 00:30:01`, sorry for the confusion. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Is you time column also set as cateogry and not date ? Could you share the piece of data/code that cannot be converted into character ?

Comment: @tom the time data was in `"POSIXt"` format. I've uploaded a sample of the data for your reference:)

Comment: In what your shared everything is in charcater for me, could you share the output of `str()`?

Comment: @tom sorry tom I may not be able to share the str() output as this is an analogy to the actual data. But I have checked that `"area"` and `"building"` are both factor data type.

Comment: Ok, it is a bit difficult. With a guess have you tried with dplyr something like `data %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)` ? If POSIXt is problematic with dplyr change it beforehand with `data$time <- as.character(data$time)`. And just in case before doing that, you did store `as.character(df$area)` in `df$area` with `<-` ?

Comment: Yeah, but I'll check what you said again. Thanks tom